# How to create/use a namespace-based PHP autoloader that loads classes, as well as constants and functions?

Tags: php, function, class, namespaces, constants

I have the following autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $class = ltrim($class, '\\');
    $filename  = '';
    $namespace = '';

    if ($last_ns_pos = strripos($class, '\\')) {
        $namespace = strtolower(substr($class, 0, $last_ns_pos));
        $class = substr($class, $last_ns_pos + 1);
        $filename  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    $filename .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

    require $filename;
});
```

If I want to load `MyApp\Library\ClassOne`, this works fine because the class is located in `/MyApp/Library/ClassOne.php`. This fulfills [one function of namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php); however, I want to be able to autoload files of constants and functions (something like `MyApp\Constants` and `MyApp\Functions` located in `MyApp\Constants.php` and `MyApp\Functions.php`, respectively).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP currently (as of PHP 5.5) doesn't support autoloading of anything other than classes.

The ability to autoload functions and constants is currently under discussion as a feature that may be added to the next version (ie PHP 5.6), but a decision on that has not yet been finalised.

See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/autofunc for more detail.

Comment: Ah! So I was trying the impossible. Thank you for the RFC link.